# Admob sdk not-compliant with google play ad policy?

Tags: google-play, admob, ads

i added ads in my app when I test it, there is no such ads appear on my screen with full internet access.

I search in log cat and I found this : Admob sdk not-compatible with google play ad policy

[image]

so what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jar downloadable from

> https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android

But it is going to be deprecated in a few days. You should remove that jar from your project and include the Google Play Services in your project in order to use the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

> https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play

If you follow the steps all are similar to the steps you have done with the jar.